# How to tell if a filename is a directory, not a file

Tags: bash, unix

I need to check if a parameter passed to a bash script is a folder or a file. It may or may not end with `/`

```
xpath=$(dirname "$1")
```

strips out the dirname if there was no trailing `/`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the file `a` and dir `t`.

You can use the command `file`:

```
$ file t
t: directory
$ file a
a: ASCII text
```

Or also the `-f` (file) and `-d` (dir) flags.

```
$ [ -f a ] && echo "this is a file"
this is a file
$ [ -f t ] && echo "this is a file"
$
$ [ -d t ] && echo "this is a dir"
this is a dir
$ [ -d a ] && echo "this is a dir"
$
```

Comment: why is this one answer instead of two? the second part is spot on, the first one is not to be recommended for scripting/programming imho.

Answer (score 1):

use "test -f" or "test -d" with the path. Though "dirname" always returns name of directory, never a filename, however it may return a directory in which file resides, or a directory in which directory resides, depending if argument is file or directory. "basename" returns filename or directory without preceeding path it resides in.